# PrimeNG - Use trueValue/falseValue on p-checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, angular8, primeng

I'm trying to implement a p-checkbox on Angular8 with true and false value as string and not as boolean.
So I tried this code below:

```
<p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox" inputId="mycheckbox" 
[trueValue]="'CB_OUI'" [falseValue]="'CB_NON'"></p-checkbox>
```

but I always get this error message:

> Can't bind to 'trueValue' since it isn't a known property of
> 'p-checkbox'.

but I don't understand why because in the [doc](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/checkbox) there are `trueValue` and `falseValue`...

If anyone has an idea, thx for your help.

Comment: Can I know which version of `primeng` that you used?

Comment: Hi @YongShun ! The version in my package.json is "^9.0.2" with angular8 and effectively in primeNg9 there isn't any trueValue/falseValue ! Well done ! 
I guess now I just have to do a ngOnChange with a ternary or something ! Thx

Comment: Hi, checked `[trueValue]` and `[falseValue]` is introduced in version 12. You need to install primeng 12.

Comment: ahah too fast ! I've just edited my comment ! Thank you for your answer !

Comment: @YongShun Is that possible for you to write your comment in answer, so this question goes away from the "unanswered" pool ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, `[trueValue]` and `[falseValue]` Input properties are only supported for [PrimeNG v12.2.0](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/checkbox). As these properties are not found in previous versions.

---

### Solution(s)

**Solution 1: For PrimeNG v12.2.0**

Either you have to install the latest version of PrimeNG.
(Note: Beware of the compatibility with your current Angular version).

**Solution 2: For before PrimeNG v12.2.0**

Create another variable (store string value) and apply `onChange` event to update the variable based on `myCheckbox`.

Make sure to call `change()` in `ngOnInit()` to initialize the variable.

> .component.ts

```js
mycheckboxWithStringValue: string = '';

ngOnInit() {
  // Init mycheckboxWithStringValue
  this.change();
}

change() {
  this.mycheckboxWithStringValue = this.mycheckbox ? 'CB_OUI' : 'CB_NON';
}
```

> .component.html

```
<p-checkbox
  [(ngModel)]="mycheckbox"
  (onChange)="change()"
  name="mycheckbox"
  inputId="mycheckbox"
  binary="true"
></p-checkbox>
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-frvtkr)

Comment: And how can we acheive that with reactive forms?

Comment: Hi, can I know which PrimeNG version you are used?

Comment: Hello, PrimeNg 11. The last version supports trueValue/falseValue inputs , it's very helpful but with v11 i still don't know how to use that correctly

Comment: Hi, the concept is quite similar to `[(ngModel)]`. 1. New variable to hold a string value. 2. Subscribe to control's `valueChanges` event to update the variable. 3. Initialize control's value to fire `valueChanges` event. Check out this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qaomcm?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure that your imports are correct. In your app.module.ts file:

```
import {CheckboxModule} from 'primeng/checkbox';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    CheckboxModule
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Yes, ain't got no problems with the import ...